# My manuscript status says that one referee sent a message but not a report

Tags: publications, peer-review, physics, journal-workflow

About three weeks ago, I submitted a paper to a highly reputable physics journal. (I had another paper recently published in this journal as well.) I have been checking the status continuously, and today I saw the following as a follow-up to a referee request:

> message received (not a report)

I am curious about this status update, as I have never encountered it before. What does this notification mean – rejection of my paper or acceptance?  It would be really appreciated if anyone could share experience on this.

Comment: PRL? The referee probably declined to review the article. The Editor will likely try to find a new referee now. Good luck!

Comment: @Bubble Any possible reason why a referee would decline to review?

Comment: Most likely time constraints or they don't feel that they're sufficiently knowledgeable in the field to asses the quality of the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that they received some communication from the referee other than a report.  Different journals have different workflows for referees.  Some do not send the manuscript until a referee has agreed to referee the work.  Some let the referee see the manuscript and give a short-ish deadline for the referee to decide whether they can eventually send a report.  Some other journals (such as the journals of the American Physical Society), send the manuscript and ask for the referee to send them back a report, without ever asking for the confirmation that the referee can do the job.

I suspect the journal works using the second system.  This is significant, because the first response that the editor might receive from a referee may be the final report.  Or it might not be; the potential referee might write back to decline the assignment or to ask for more time.  So it is important to identify whether a response received from the referee is or is not a report--and that's what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response. Actually it is a APS journal. Last time when I sent them my manuscript, referees had directly sent the reports (no initial message). Therefore, after seeing this status update I am nervous. :). On the other hand, as per my understanding, this cannot be a rejection, because in that case referee supposed to send a report.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this status message in the APS system can also be caused by referees agreeing to review (which they do not have to).